# mirth can connect with Cache,sybase,informix database?

Tags: caching, sybase, informix, mirth

I want to know that mirth can connect with other database like(cache,sybase,informix).
I am getting no way to connect all above database using mirth
because In Mcsm(mirth connect server manager) there is only few database option like(postgres,durby,oracle,mysql).
so is there any alternate way to use url of (cache,informaix database) in mcsm.
please help me any help is highly apprecialble.

Comment: Those are the databases currently supported, and it is not a small list.

Answer (score 0):

`derby`
`postgres`
`mysql`
`oracle`
`Sql server2000`
`sql server`

-These are the various different RDBMS system that Mirth can support at this moment in the latest version `2.2.2.6388`

Having said that, it means that the `mirthdb` the database that mirth uses for its *integration* purpose can be configured/installed on any of the above RDBMS systems, most of the times its either postgre or mysql.

Other than this, there is no other means of connecting to `informix` (even though I would love to see that happen), that depends on Mirth corp.

Comment: Well it's not entirely dependent on Mirth Corp.  It is Open Source after all and the Java code is available for modification and enhancement.  If you're not a Java programmer, then you are left to depending on the Mirth community or a hired programmer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a JDBC driver (.jar file) for the other database(s), you could try these steps:

> - Add the .jar file to the $MIRTH_HOME/custom-lib directory
> - Add/Change a driver entry to the file $MIRTH_HOME/conf/dbdrivers.xml

I'm not sure if that will let you choose other databases in MCSM or only allows you to choose them in Mirth channels (Database Reader, Database Writer, etc), but it's worth a try.  I am unable to test it right now.

See http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/mirth/Server+Configuration